# How to play League of Legends when Cloud Flare is blacklisting your IP?

Tags: league-of-legends, networking

My IP Address was incorrectly blacklisted due to strange behavior, I assume, of IP's in my "IP Neighborhood" (according to Cisco's Talos IP reputation tracker)
This means, among other things, that I must complete a captcha when I access na.leagueoflegends.com and login.riotgames.com

However, completing the CloudFlare captcha only gets me access via a browser. The game client does not present a captcha interface, nor does it respect the cookies of the browser that show I've completed said captcha.

Is there a way to play League of Legends or am I screwed?
Unfortunately my IP is static, so I can't do the usual IP renewal process, and I've already whitelisted it on Project Honeypot so I'm in a tough situation, especially because they are blacklisting an entire IP range and not my specific IP (my IP is squeaky clean)

Comment: This sounds like more of a question for Riot Support than for us, to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to a VPN, which will display another IP instead of your own. Your ping will probably become slightly higher depending on how far away the VPN server is. I'd recommend [Mudfish](https://mudfish.net/) for gaming latency, but I cannot vouch for its privacy.

Comment: Although it's unlikely  that the Ban is legitimate, given the OP's Situation, Ban evasion in this manner is likely to be against the Terms of Service for League of Legends. Probably not something they will want to do if they are hoping to get unbanned at a later date.

Comment: @Stese OP is not banned from League, it's just that his IP address is within a "block" that has been labeled as suspicious (either by Riot or the ISP) and it requires a captcha to prove the IP doesn't belong to a bot. There is no ban evasion happening if he uses a VPN.

Comment: @Stese OP asked for a solution, not a way to get support, which has been suggested by Schism in the comments.

Comment: @MageXy If the OP is using an IP that has been blocked by a provider, he's been blocked, even if it's not intended for him. Using a VPN to get around this would still be seen as Ban Evasion.

Comment: @Yuu : correct hence my comment advising that a VPN is not a solution. Getting support is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Contact Riot and/or Cloud flare for support on the issue. Provide them with the evidence you've gathered, and see what that does. I'd recommend against trying to spoof or hide your IP as it may constitute a break of the Terms and Conditions anyway.

Failing that, contact your ISP and see if they can move your IP to another range.

Answer (score 0):

An medical anatomy quiz app on my wife's phone was phoning home to China hourly. Deleting it cleared up the cloudflare warnings. I was able to find this with a router security malware detection page which showed the MAC address of the originating device. I also enabled IPv6 but I'm not sure that fixed anything.